# Create a def to Calculate the average time - there are multiple columns - Python or SQL

Tags: python, sql

I have two columns with the following data: date of access to the site and column with the email of the client who accessed it; many customers access on more than one different day.

What business question do i need to answer: what average time of purchase interest per customer. that is, I need to make the differences between the dates (in days) and create a column with the average of each customer. Some customers accessed on more than 3 different dates, so I believe a function is needed to solve.

The name of my dataframe is dt, and the columns are: data and email_proposta

The date is in this format: 2016-01-01

What business question do i need to answer: what average time of purchase interest per customer. that is, I need to make the differences between the dates (in days) and create a column with the average of each customer. Some customers accessed on more than 3 different dates, so I believe a function is needed to solve.

Comment: So, if a customer has more than one visit, you want to know the average number of days between visits?  Remember if there are N visits, all you need is the last minus the first, divided by (N-1).  You don't have to compute each one separately.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Here I am making a temp table in a database. Of course make sure you do not break any production database.

Notice in the example that the third client does not show up, since he only visited the site once.

Using sqlite3:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)  # aim at your database
c = conn.cursor()

# dangerQuery = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp'
# c.execute(dangerQuery)

query = 'CREATE TABLE temp (date text, email_proposta text);'
c.execute(query)
query = "INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('2016-01-01', 'first@client.net'), ('2016-01-30', 'first@client.net'), ('2016-02-05', 'first@client.net');"
c.execute(query)
query = "INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('2016-01-02', 'second@client.net'), ('2016-01-06', 'second@client.net'), ('2016-01-06', 'second@client.net');"
c.execute(query)
query = "INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('2016-01-30', 'first@client.net'), ('2016-01-30', 'first@client.net'), ('2016-02-05', 'first@client.net');"
c.execute(query)
query = "INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('2016-03-13', 'third@client.net');"
c.execute(query)

query_Select = "SELECT DISTINCT date, email_proposta FROM temp ORDER BY email_proposta,date DESC;"
c.execute(query_Select)

rows = c.fetchall()

format = '%Y-%m-%d'
visits_dic = {}  # email: [date1, date2, ..]

for row in rows:
    email = row[1]
    visit_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], format) 
    if email not in visits_dic:
        visits_dic[email] = [visit_date]
    else:
        visits_dic[email].append(visit_date)

client_gap_dic = {}  # email: average days between

for email, dates in visits_dic.items():
    if len(dates) < 2:
        continue
    daysBetween = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(dates) - 1:
        days = dates[i] - dates[i+1]
        days = days.days
        daysBetween.append(days)
        i += 1
    average = sum(daysBetween) / len(daysBetween)

    # finally save your findings:
    client_gap_dic[email] = average
```